# Is Leia still a princess in the new canon?

Tags: star-wars

I’m a bit confused on some of the politics mentioned in *Bloodline*, where royal families are discussed. Is she still considered a princess of a people even though Alderaan has been destroyed? There was mention of her leading a planet but she passed it on to someone else, and again I’m confused on how it is all connected.

To put it bluntly, is she still a princess, and what was the deal with the planet Bail was going to offer her?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes

Consider C-3PO’s explanation of the proper protocol for addressing Leia:

> “Pleased to meet you, ma’am.” Wait. Was that right? “I mean, Senator.
>   Or, uh, Princess—no, Your Highness!”
>
> A golden protocol droid shuffling up behind them said, “Either Senator
>   or Your Highness at first reference. Ma’am or **Princess Leia** is
>   acceptable thereafter.”
>
> <sub>*Bloodline*</sub>

Given that C-3PO is an expert on protocol, I think we can say that Leia remains a princess.

Interestingly, a surviving Alderaanian referred to her as *Queen*:

[image]

It would seem logical that, in the absence of any surviving members of the Alderaan royal family, she would become queen. Given that C-3PO does not recommend this form of address later, however, I think we can say that *formally* speaking she lacks some qualification of queenhood (an official coronation ceremony, for example).

I believe the planet the question refers to is [Birren](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Birren). Since Leia was the closest relative to the previous governor (by adoption, not by blood), she was entitled to the governorship. She chose to pass the governership to Lady Carise Sindian, however (from whom it was later revoked).